# shinydasboard not loading R

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

I am creating shiny application with two files: `ui.R` and `server.R`. Each of them looks like:

```
# ui.R
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Content"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs", sidebarMenuOutput("menu"))
  ),

  dashboardBody(
............................
```

and

```
# server.R
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)    

load(file = "table word freq.RData")

function(input, output,session) {

  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Tags", tabName="m1", icon = icon("database"),
               menuSubItem("Tags1", tabName = "m1"),
               menuSubItem("Tags2", tabName = "m2"),
               menuSubItem("Tags3", tabName = "m3")
               ),
................
```

As you see, I'm using `shinydashboard` package, but when I press `Run App` I get an error:

```
Warning: Error in ..stacktraceon..: could not find function "dashboardPage"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    1: shiny::runApp
Error : could not find function "dashboardPage".
```

Have you any idea why `library(shinydashboard)` doesn't attach to my code as other packages?

Comment: Try including the `library(shiny)` and `library(shinyDashboard)` into both files.

Comment: Thank you. It worked! ^_^ But there is unclear for me why I get an error, when these libraries are only in `server.R`? In `RShiny` documentary it is clearly said, that you need define packages only in `Server.R` file, not both...

Comment: Was wondering that myself, but no time to experiment :). But I guess the `ui.R` is being compiled (interpeted?) in a seperate environment to the `server.R` one.

Comment: of course, you saved my day today:)

Comment: also add the R tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the documentation states that you need to define the shiny package only in the `server.R` file, and not necessarily the `ui.R` file, it seems to be referring to "normal" shiny apps only, not "Shiny Dashboards". It looks like R-Studio preloads the `shiny` library for a shiny file named `ui.R`, but not the `shinydashboard` library. Perhaps they though this might lead to unwanted conflicts.

It is seems inconsistent to me as well, so I checked RTVS, and it behaves the same way.

So you need to have a `library(shinydashboard)` as the first line in the `ui.R` file of a Shiny Dashboard app.